# determine and classify all singular points of $\frac{z}{e^{\pi z}-1}*\log(z^2+4)$

Tags: complex-analysis

determine and classify all singular points of

\begin{equation*}
\frac{z}{e^{\pi z}-1}\ast \log(z^2+4)
\end{equation*}

Obviously one sees that the singularities occur when $z = 2in$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. The main problem here is that $\log(z^2 + 4)$ has a negative term in the brackets which confuses me a lot...

I can only say that the point zero is a removable singularity, by the fact that the functions in the nominator and denominator have order 1 in 0. How do i classify the other points?

Kees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think $0$ is removable? $\log(4) \ne 0$.  The only zeros of $\log(z^2+4)$ are when $z^2+4 = 1$, and those are not zeros of the denominator.

The $\log(z^2+4)$ introduces branch points at $z = \pm 2 i$ and branch cuts, whose location depends on which branch of logarithm you use.

Comment: made a little error, in the fraction there need to be a $z$ see edited post.

Comment: OK, now $0$ is removable.

Comment: but how do you classify the other points then?

Comment: $\pm 2 i$ are branch points (and thus not isolated singularities).  Other integer multiples of $2i$ are still poles unless they are on the branch cuts (as they would be if you used the principal branch of log), in which case again they are not isolated singularities.